# Randomly choose a number in a specific range with a specific multiple in python

Tags: python, random

I have the following numbers:

100, 200, 300, 400 ... 20000

And I would like to pick a random number within that range. Again, that range is defined as 100:100:20000. Furthermore, by saying 'within that range', I don't mean randomly picking a number from 100->20000, such as 105. I mean randomly choosing a number from the list of numbers available, and that list is defined as 100:100:20000.

How would I do that in Python?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use [`random.randrange`](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html#random.randrange) :

```
random.randrange(100, 20001, 100)
```

Comment: +1.  From the docs: `This is equivalent to choice(range(start, stop, step)), but doesn’t actually build a range object.`

Comment: Out of curiosity I tried a benchmark of this answer vs. `random.randint(1, 2001) * 100` which it turns out is pretty much the exact same.  A difference of about 1 - 2 hundredths of a second for 1M iterations.

Comment: @sberry2A: `random.randrange(100, 20001, 100)` is clearer than `random.randint(1, 2001) * 100`.  Performance should be similar because neither generates a sequence.

Answer (score 6):

For Python 3:

```
import random

random.choice(range(100, 20100, 100))
```

Comment: Inefficient.  From the docs for random.randrange: "Return a randomly selected element from range(start, stop, step). This is equivalent to choice(range(start, stop, step)), but doesn’t actually build a range object."  Using `xrange` would not avoid this problem.  `random.choice` must evaluate the entire iterator from `xrange` for its choice to be random.

Comment: @Wooble:  Nope.  `random.choice` just generates a single random index and uses that to access the appropriate element of the sequence.  Note that the argument to `random.choice` must support `len` and item access by index: `random.choice` doesn't accept arbitrary iterables.

Comment: @Tom Zych: Based on Mark Dickenson's comment your answer doesn't work on Python 3 which returns an iterator for `range`.

Comment: @Mark: Um, yes, it does. The docs say "iterable" and I tested it too. I agree it's probably less efficient than `randrange`, though.

Comment: @Tom Zych:  I'll take your word that it works.  But it's still inefficient as it has to evaluate the entire iterator before choosing.  It's like using a hammer instead of a nail gun (and you happen to have both tools on hand).

Comment: @Tom, @Steven:  Nowhere did I say Tom's answer doesn't work on Python 3.  It does, precisely because `range` supports `len` and access by index.

Comment: I've profiled this and it's actually *faster* than `randrange` (in Python 3; it's horribly slow in Python 2, but `xrange` makes it better than randrange).

Comment: @Mark: That's interesting. Do you mean it can randomly access one item of an iterable without generating the preceding ones? Or just that it doesn't have to generating the **succeeding** ones?

Comment: Ok.  I have read the source.  Relevant implementation detail (minus error handling): `def __getitem__(self, i): return self.start + self.step * i`.  So it doesn't generate preceding values.

Comment: Cool, didn't know generators could do that. Thanks.

Comment: I removed my -1.  I think `random.randrange` is clearer, but I'm +1 because of my ignorant comments.

Comment: @Tom:  `random.choice` expects a sequence rather than an iterable:  that is, it expects something that has `__len__` and `__getitem__` methods.  `range` in Python 3 (and `xrange` in Python 2) have those methods.  There's no iteration going on at all.

Comment: @Steven:  I'd also agree that the `random.randrange` solution is clearer / more direct.

Comment: I think this solution is clearer, and given that Python 3 range returns a Sequence, they should probably remove `randrange` now.

Answer (score 2):

from python manual:

> [`random.randrange([start], stop[, step])`](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html#random.randrange)
>
> Return a randomly selected element from range(start, stop, step). This
> is equivalent to choice(range(start, stop, step)), but doesn’t
> actually build a range object.

Answer (score 1):

This would do it

```
print random.choice(xrange(100, 20100, 100);
```

But this is probably better:

```
print int(round(random.randint(100, 200001),-2))
```

@mouad's answer looks the best to me.

**EDIT**
Out of curiosity I tried a benchmark of this answer vs. `random.randint(1, 2001) * 100` which it turns out is pretty much the exact same. A difference of about 1 - 2 hundredths of a second for 1M iterations.